# How to change the print size of an image in mm on command line?

Tags: shell, imagemagick, image-manipulation

ImageMagick seems to be best to convert image files on the command line. However it only supports changing the size in pixels and the resolution in inch per pixel but not the **print size** (as shown with the command `identify -verbose`). I'd like to:

- quickly get the image print size in mm
- change the image print size (by setting either height or width or both to a new value in mm)

This should be able with simple shell scripting, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

The only *absolute* dimension for images are *pixels*.

*Resolution*, *mm* or *density* or *resolution* do only come into play when you *render* the image on a certain surface (screen display, paper printout).

These have their own built-in, hardware-dependent resolution. If you know it, you can compute the *mm* values for the image dimensions, provided you want to render it in its "natural size".

Very often you do not want the "natural size" -- sometimes you may want: "fill the Letter-sized paper with the image" (scale to fit). If that happens, the same image will have to be scaled up or down -- but the screen or printer resolution will not change, it's only that an interpolation algorithm will start to add pixels to fill the gap (scale up) or remove pixels to make the picture appear smaller (scale down).

So before someone can give an algorithm about how to compute the "image size in mm" (in the image's natural size) you need to know the resolution of the target device (screen or printer).

---

**Edit:**

If you embed a given image (which has its size in pixels) into a PDF (where the source document comes for example from LaTeX), you still have to specify...

- ...either at which *resolution* you want the image be rendered on the page
- ...or at which *size* (either in mm or in % of the page dimensions) you want the image rendered.

You cannot determine **both** these parameters at the same time without resampling the image. Pick one, and the other is implicitly determined by your pick.

To give an example.

Assume your original image is 2160x1440 pixels.

Your LaTeX -> PDF transformation is done by Ghostscript. Ghostscript internally uses a default resolution of 720 dpi for all raster objects. So unless you set "resolution" explicitly to a different value for your PDF conversion, the image will have a size of 3x2 inches (76.2 x 50.8 mm) on a PDF or print page.

If you set the resolution to 90 dpi, the image will have a size of 24x16 inches (609.6 x 406.4 mm) on the page.

If you set the resolution to 270 dpi (which is close to the commonly used 300 dpi), the image size transforms to 8x5.333 inches (203.2 x 135.5 mm).

So the formula for a shell script is:

```
 # 25.4 mm == 1 inch

  image_width_px=W                      # in pixels (integer)
 image_height_px=H                      # in pixels (integer)
 resolution=R                           # in pixels/inch

  image_width_in_inch=$((W / R))        #   Shell arithmetics: does only handle
 image_height_in_inch=$((H / R))        #+  and return integers!

  image_width_in_mm=$(( $((W / R)) * 254/10 ))
 image_height_in_mm=$(( $((H / R)) * 254/10 ))

 # use 'bc' to achieve higher precision arithmetics:
  precise_image_width_in_mm=$( echo \
                               "$image_width_px  / $resolution * 25.4" \
                               | bc -l )
 precise_image_height_in_mm=$( echo \
                               "$image_height_px / $resolution * 25.4" \
                               | bc -l )
```

Comment: well, if I include an image via LaTeX in a PDF there is the paper size. One can also modify this "image size" in Gimp" how without image-magick?

Comment: Yes, there is the paper size. But you tell your conversion process at least one of these two: (1) which resolution should it use for the image? That implicitly sets the image size on the page.  (2) which area size should the image cover? This implicitly sets the image resolution. -- If you want to set **both** (unless they match exactly) you'll get a different image with a different number of pixels compared to the original one....

Comment: Thanks! Not I only need to find out hob to get and set the values via the corresponding command line arguments. I hoped that someone had already done this.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you just asked a question about the task you want to let ImageMagick perform on your picture, and stat that you want to "give the size in mm'?

Comment: Sorry I though I have asked clearly. Feel free to edit my question!

Comment: @Jacob: No, Jacob, it's *your* question, and *your* benefit if you state it as clearly as possible. My interest in this topic is exhausted for now. I tried hard and as good as I could to help you. But I have no idea what you need it for.... Also, my suggestion was for you to create a *new* question outlining what you want to finally achieve (the bit about converting to mm is only a small piece, right?)

Comment: `identify -verbose in.png` gives a print size. How is this computed / stored?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to solve it with [my own script in Perl](https://gist.github.com/3246780). One must calculate the dots per inch based on the size in pixels and the requested print size, as explained by Kurt Pfeilfe in his answer.

```
sub getsize {
  my $file = shift;
  my $info = do { # avoid the shell, no escaping needed
    my @args = ('-format','%G %x%y','-units','PixelsPerInch',$file);
    open my $fh, "-|", "identify", @args or die "$!\n";
    <$fh>;
  };
  if ($info =~ /^(\d+)x(\d+) (\d+) PixelsPerInch(\d+) PixelsPerInch/) {
    my ($px,$py,$dx,$dy) = ($1,$2,$3,$4);
    my ($sx,$sy) = map { $_ * 25.4 } ($px/$dx, $py/$dy);
    return ($px,$py,$dx,$dy,$sx,$sy);
  } else {
    die $info;
  }
}

foreach my $file (@ARGV) {
  if ($file =~ /^(\d*)(x(\d+))?mm$/) {
    ($mx,$my) = ($1,$3);
  } elsif( -e $file ) {
    my ($w,$h);
    if ($mx || $my) {
      my ($px,$py,$dx,$dy,$sx,$sy) = getsize($file);
      my $rx = 25.4 * ( $mx ? ($px/$mx) : ($py/$my) );
      my $ry = 25.4 * ( $my ? ($py/$my) : ($px/$mx) );
      system qw(convert -units PixelsPerInch -density),
          sprintf("%.0fx%.0f",$rx,$ry), $file, $file;
    }
    printf "$file: %dx%d at %dx%ddpi = %dx%dmm", getsize($file);
  } else {
    die "file not found: $file\n";
  }
}
```

The script does not support fractions of milimeters, feel free to modify [the source](https://gist.github.com/3246780).